# What set is this dark grey remote with orange buttons from?

Tags: piece-information, set-identification, software, piece-usage

This is what the front looks like:

[image: Front view]

This is what the back looks like, I'm 90% sure it says 4272 at the top:

[image: Back view]

This is the remote control of a set I got ages ago, when I was still a little boy. I lost the receiver-part, but from my memory it looked like a bulky base for a car and had a antenna with the actual receiver on it. I'm trying to use the remote in a project, but its turning out to be more difficult than I thought, and I hoped that finding the actual set would help me. The main thing I need is the IR details/protocol so I can read the remote with a IR receiver and use it for tons of fun stuff. I hope someone can help me out.

PS. I know it looks a lot like the Bionicle Manas set, but its slightly different, notice the channel switches on the front sides of the remotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like part [2162c01 - Electric, RC Controller Racer Complete Assembly (Black Bottom, Red Buttons)](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2162c01&idColor=10#T=C&C=10) from RC Nitro Flash (set 4589).